# Parsing text using Python

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, python, string, python3

I have this text;

```
{bc}having or marked by great {a_link|volume} or bulk {bc}{sx|large
```

I was trying to get something like this;

```
having or marked by great volume or bulk
```

I tried doing this with regular expression module,

```
import re

text = "{bc}having or marked by great {a_link|volume} or bulk {bc}{sx|large"

new_text1 = re.sub("{","",text)
new_text2 = re.sub("}","",new_text1)
new_text3 = re.sub("a_link","",new_text2)
new_text4 = re.sub("|","",new_text3)
final_text = re.sub("bcsx.*","",new_text4)
```

Only then I get the desired output, but this took me 5 steps! Can this be done more easily?

Comment: Presumably you're trying to rid your text of curly-braces and associated text.  So why is the final curly-pair incomplete? And what about the word 'volume'? Is it an error for 'volume' to show up in your output?

Comment: This appears to be written in some structured document format. Do you happen to know what the format is called? Could you show a bit more of the document? Is the last `sx` tag (for want of a better word) continued and closed on the next line?

Comment: This is probably text from an online dictionary? https://dictionaryapi.com/products/json#sec-2.tokens  This also probably means you want to replace `{bc}` with `: `, right?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

At the command line:

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \{ .*? [ \} | $ ]//;'  file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g{ \{ .*? [ \} | $ ] } = "";'  file
```

Does it have to be Python? Raku is a good choice, especially if you plan on tackling thorny Unicode text via Regular Expressions. Above (example 1) uses the familiar `s///` substitution operator. Example 2 uses Raku's newer 'assignment' substitution format, e.g. `s{…} = "…"`.

Either example above: Raku searches for a `\{` opening-curlie, `.*?` zero-or-more instances of any-character (searched non-greedily), followed by a `[`…`]` square-bracket-delineated group consisting of either `\}` closing-curlie or (`|` pipe operator) a `$` end-of-string zero-width assertion.

You should note that this regex solution doesn't address nested bracing. To handle nested bracing, see [Tilde for nesting structures](https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Tilde_for_nesting_structures).

Sample Input:

```
{bc}having or marked by great {a_link|volume} or bulk {bc}{sx|large
```

Sample Output:

```
having or marked by great  or bulk
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#s///_in-place_substitution
https://raku.org/